# output java.exe -cp someclass to a file

Tags: java, windows, weblogic

I am trying to run a weblogic multicast test every 2 hours for 5 minutes and output it to a file (in windows env)

The command syntax looks like this.

```
java -cp E:\bea1033\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar utils.MulticastTest -n NODE1 -a 224.2.2.2 -p 7002
```

I can run this via command line and > it to a text file but then I have to hit a key to stop it. I have tried to put this in a bat file and use task scheduler but the task scheduler does not stop the java command and therefore the multicast test continues to run forever.

I have also just tried to enter the above command in task scheduler but the command will not start for some reason. (I am still trying to figure out why it wont start)

Can anybody point me in the right direction or give suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom class that will start a thread which exits after 5 minutes, and starts the multicast test in the main thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000L);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };
    t.start();

    utils.MulticastTest.main(args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JB that pointed me in the right direction. Due to my lack of (anything other than PHP) programming skills I used AutoIT to write what I needed in 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set in task properties to stop it after 5 mins? 
[image]

Comment: I have tried that but since I have a bat file that launches the Java.exe (with params) it does not stop that java.exe process.

Comment: @Stewy it does on mine... how you start java in your bat? What happens if you just run bat and force close it's cmd window?

Comment: I am running it like this on a windows server 2003 box....I also have to run it 3 times on 3 different servers.

java -cp E:\bea1033\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar utils.MulticastTest -n NODE1 -a 224.2.2.2 -p 7002 >> logger.log

Comment: @Stewy It looks to me as a problem with stopping the task altogether (not because it's a bat file) either due to permissions or some other dependency. Is there anything reported in the log (under  Advanced->View log)? Have a look also here, maybe it helps [Scheduled Tasks appear hung in the “Running” state on Windows  Server 2003 based systems](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rspitz/archive/2010/11/07/scheduled-tasks-appear-hung-in-the-running-state-on-windows-server-2003-based-systems.aspx). Sorry I cannot be of more help... but it looks your config specific